# Huffman Coding. Decode from binary file

Tags: c#

Huffman Coding task.

what I doing. 
Read string from file, prepare Huffman structure, encode string to bits and save that bits to binary file.

What I need:
Decode string from binary file but encoding and decoding must be independent. After closing app for e.q.

I saving to binary file like that:

```
A:000;l:001;a:10; :110;m:010;k:011;o:1110;t:1111;
00000110110010101100111110111110;
```

And need to read it and decode. So I think I need to build Huffman structure again from that but how?

Answer (score 1):

I see this options

- Encoder and decoder always use the same tree, it never changes. So the decoder already knows, that `000` means `A`.
- Tree is appended before the message in binary format. Encoder and decoder have to know the exact format for storing the tree, there are many possibilities how to do this. In simplest case there would be number of encoded characters and for every character its ascii code, length of Huffman code and the code itself.
- Tree is built on the fly using adaptive Huffman coding, but it does not seem to be Your case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know `A:000;l:001;a:10; :110;m:010;k:011;o:1110;t:1111;` You can try to traverse the string `00000110110010101100111110111110` a character at a time. also have a switch statement for each of the characters, and their code. When ever you come across a case, for eg`000`, you can output A. This is one way I can see you being able to go back to the string. I am sure there is a better way out there.

hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, thanks for help! I'd work. But I have that code in binary file what is: 0101010101110101010101010. And I need to find that A is 000. The 'A', ':' and ';' have different length codes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Adaptive Huffman", it's not usual to decide yourself what code to use for each character.

The usual sequence is

1. Analyze the text to be encoded. That means counting the occurrences of each character. In the English language 'e' would be more frequent than 'x', 'y' or 'z' for example.
2. Sort the arrays of char/occurrence in ascending order.
3. Build a BTree - that means combining the two lowest, adding their counts and making a new tree node. Ignore those two and look for the next pair of lowest occurrences (which might include the node you just made). This continues until you end up with a BTree with one root. (There are lots of helpful images of this). I can explain this in more detailed steps if necessary.
4. From the root of the tree you "walk" to each leaf. For each "left" add a '0' and for each right a '1'. When you reach the leaf, you have the code for that letter. If your text has many e's it will have the shortest code and no other code will start with the same sequence of bits. This is the idea, the most frequent characters have the shortest code, thus bigger memory savings.
5. Now, by walking the tree you have the code (varying lengths) for each character.
6. Encode your text to a string of bits.
7. To decode you use the same tree. You say it must work "after closing app" so you will have to store the tree in some form with the encoded data.

In your comment you mention the problem with having varying length codes. There is no ambiguity. In an extreme case, if you had more e's than all other characters combined, the tree would be very lopsided. 'e' would be encoded as '1' and all other letters would have codes of varying lengths, beginning with 0.

Comment: Did this help? I can go into more detail on step 3 if needed.
I have used Huffman to save space for "tags" in embedded software, where memory was limited.